# How do I set the background image of header from a separate jsx file?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, jsx

I can't get the background image of the header to show.

Do I have to give the file path relative to where the component is or just import the image in the jsx file and set the url there? I tried both but I might be doing it wrong. Any suggestions?

This is the component in which I am trying to set the header background image for.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Typography, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { header, images } from '../../datamodel/configItems/ComponentRenderableData';
import medicine from '../../assets/images/medicine.png';
import { hero } from '../../assets/jsx/appStyle';

class Hero extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header className={hero.header}>    
                <Typography>{header.header}</Typography>
                <Typography>{header.paragraph}</Typography>
                <Button>{header.btn}</Button>
                <img className={hero.img} src={medicine} alt={images.medicine.alt} />
            </header>
        );
    }
}

export default Hero;
```

This is the file that I am using to style the Hero component.

```
import { images } from '../../datamodel/configItems/ComponentRenderableData';

export const hero = {
    header: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${images.blob_path.img})`,
        backgroundSize: "contain, cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        height: "90vh",
        width: "100%",
        backgroundPosition: "top left",
        overflow: "hidden"
    },
    img: {
        ... more styling
    }
};
```

The background image of header element should be setting but it is not. There are no errors that show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there more to your hero style object your exporting? I see that you have a key of header in there but I also see you calling hero.img but don't see a key of img.

Second thing, I see your importing {images} into your component style. Is it pointing to the right url? Because you could also just have your background image in your images directory then

import backgroundImage from '../pathToYourImageDirectory/backgroundImage'

and then set background: url(`${backgroundImage}`);